# How to extend console.log?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there anyway to write a prototype function, or a function that runs whenever `console.log` is called? (And grabs the console.log parameter). I am about 100 KB's in for my web-based game server, and have hundreds of console.logs throughout my code. I would love to use the console log data and use the information later in a web-based admin panel or whatnot.

Oh, and I'm Using nodejs and [FS](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/file-system/how-to-write-files-in-nodejs).  Writing to a file is no problem, I know how to do that, but just catching the `console.log` is the issue. Any idea?

Comment: You would have to overwrite `console.log`. Why not just make a function that you use instead of `console.log` with `console.log` inside of it?

Comment: @PHPglue Would that mean searching and replacing each `console.log(e)` with a new function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `console.log` with your own function, like this

```
// Store the original version, so that you can fall back to it
var originalLogger = console.log,
    fs = require("fs"),
    writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("logs.txt");

console.log = function () {

    // Do your custom logging logic
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        writeStream.write(arguments[i]);
    }

    // You can still call the original `console.log`, with all the `arguments`
    originalLogger.apply(this, arguments);
}

console.log("Welcome");
```

Comment: That is fancy. Didn't know you were going to write it out for me. Thank you and [much appreciated.](http://i.gyazo.com/f6c0bb743bf4cfb1660e6819e64b776f.png) I'll definitely be extending and adding to it now :D

Comment: @NiCkNewman You already required `fs` in line 6. So, you don't have to do that again in line 13 :-)

Comment: This is a bad solution. Your logger does not retain information about the intended origin of the log.

Comment: @AlexandreVerri What do you mean by intended origin. Could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 1):

You can reset console.log to your custom log function, demo code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');

var l = fs.createWriteStream('abc');
console.log = function () {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
    l.write(util.format.apply(util, args));
    l.write('\n');
}
```